# How to redirect the user to another site after some time?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress for a website. If any users visits the page X from my website I want to redirect them to another site after 30 seconds.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a mix of both answer before I start looking at wordpress functions docs. I found something and add it to my header.php on my wordpress site.

```
<?php if ( is_page('Page Title') ) { ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      window.setInterval(customRedirect, 3000);
      function customRedirect() { 
         window.location = "http://www.google.com"; 
      }
   </script>
<?php } >
```

So whenever the user enters a page with that title it will make the redirect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add this javascript to your footer:

```
window.setInterval(yourfunction, 10000); //100 seconds

function yourfunction() { window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com"; }
```

Comment: I can add that, but I'm creating a page with wordpress not another html or php file. How would I specified to which page it has to work?

Answer (score 2):

In your header.php add this code inside the head tag section

```
 <head>
     <!-- your other meta element -->
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;URL='http://example.com/'">
 </head>
```

Comment: If I edit the header.php I will work for all the website. I want to work only with a specific page that I created on my wordpress site.

Comment: @Camilo Aguilar. you can put conditional statement before it. like <?php if($post->ID == 'your specific page id'): ?> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;URL='http://example.com/'"><?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 2):

useful I found the code snippet from Camilo caused the site to fall over so I changed the last line from:

```
<?php }>
```

to:

```
<?php }; ?>
```

and now it works.