# direct users with set_transient

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress, transient

i wanna redirect users every 12hours to another page 
and want use header(location:url) and set_transient
i use this codes

```
$transient = get_transient( 'name_my_transient' );
if ( empty( $transient ) ){
    function redirect() {
        $data = 'redirected';
        return $data;
        header('location: http://www.google.com');
    }
add_action('wp_head', 'redirect');      
set_transient('name_my_transient', $data, 60*60*12 ); 
}
```

if i remove return $data it always redirect users

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989029/how-to-redirect-the-user-to-another-site-after-some-time

Answer (score 0):

Your reflexion is good but i think you had made some mistakes on your code organization, try with this :

```
<?php
// Call your function with a top priority
add_action( 'wp_head', 'redirect', 1 );

function redirect() {
    // Get the transien
    $transient = get_transient( 'name_my_transient' );

    // If the data do not exist, set it and redirect user
    if ( $transient === false ) {

        // Set the transient for 12 hours
        set_transient('name_my_transient', 'redirected', 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ); 

        // Redirect the user with wp_redirect
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.google.com' ); exit;
    }
}
?>
```